# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Game Development's [second moderator election](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Josh Petrie] [image: Byte56]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1825001/0).

Answer (score 12):

Congratulations! I'm sure you both will do excellent.